# Why don't image Thumbnails update in Components after updating the Image's Multimedia Components?

Tags: 2011, cme

I have a component with a `Multimedia Link` field for linking to an image. When I update the Multimedia Component referenced by the field in my component, the thumbnail of the image is not updated.

#### The component containing the Multimedia Link field:

[image: Component with image]

#### The multimedia component:

[image: Image updated]

#### Here are more details on the problem I am experiencing:

I updated the Multimedia Component by updating its nombre and image.

When I open the Component containing the reference to said Multimedia Component, the name of the MM Component has been updated but not the image being displayed.

I repeated this process several times saving and reopening the component, the name of the MM Component is always updated in my Component but the image being displayed is never updated, it is always the initial image.

All this happens in the same publication.

I'm using: Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS SDLTridin 2011 SP1

I solved the problem by installing this hotfix: CM_2011.1.1.80564_tcm89-20619. I found this in their specifications : "Thumbnail view of MM Components not updating correctly".

Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: You say it is not updated. Have you tried closing and re-opening the component that links to your MM Component. It is not clear when you are expecting the image to reload..

Comment: Jaward, please consider creating and accepting an answer mentioning the solution you found for this problem (Hotfix CM_2011.1.180564_tcm89-20619)

Answer (score 1):

The component should be updated, as Chris is saying you should re-open the component to see the changes. In case it is not updated after re-opening the component, check if the component/multimedia component is not localized.

Answer (score 1):

Thumbnails of multimedia Components are cached in the UI, (a long with a lot of other items and images to improve performance).

So what you are describing sounds like a cached thumbnail, since you indicate that the title of the multimedia Component is correctly updated. To make sure you can refresh the page (or view) and see if it will clear the cache. You can do this by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> and accepting the question to leave the page (choose `yes`) if it comes up.